# Using the fancyhdr package, how do I have a footer but no header on the first page only

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, footer

I would like to have a header and a footer throughout the document, however on the first page I would like no header with the footer remaining as it is throughout the document. So far all I can do is change the the first page style to plain, however this only gives the footer to be a page number, not the information I want.

I believe I have included a minimum working example below, however it's most likely i've done something wrong as i'm quite new to this all. I'm also aware this may be marked as a duplicate question however my search has provided me no results with this issue specifically.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{Name:First Last}

\section{First page}
No header here
\clearpage
\section{Second page}
Header should be back
\end{document}
```

Comment: a) What document class do you use? b) Do you want to change only the very first page of the document (the title page) or the first page of every chapter?

Comment: a)using \documentclass[]{article} b) no, just the very first page, however the first page is not really a titlepage, just a unique title at the top of the page indicating the start (hence why I do not wish to have the header at the start)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the very first page has no header:

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{Name:First Last}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\today}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}%
}   
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother % anywhere after the first page/chapter

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using article as the document class, I should have said this early, apologies. I still cannot adapt this into my code to work unfortunately, even if I change the class to book as it is here, there is still a header. Is there anyway your code could be adapted to article class and still work as intended?

Comment: Apologies - please ignore the above. I have solved that issue simply by adding \thispagestyle{plain}. The code now works. Thank you for your help and quick response.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to leave the `plain` style as it is and define a new style, let's say `firstpage`

```
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\today}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}%
}
```

and, at the very beginning of the document, issue

```
\thispagestyle{firstpage}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[L]{\today}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0mm}%
}  

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{Name:First Last}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [fancyhdr](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) manual the `\fancypagestyle` command is what you're looking for (see section 7 of the manual):

> This command can be used to redeﬁne existing pagestyles (like plain) or to deﬁne new
>   ones, e.g. if part of your document is to use a diﬀerent pagestyle.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}
\fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{Name:First Last}}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[R]{Assignment No.}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\today}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1mm}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{Test document}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```