# Number of page out of ## pages on each page

Tags: header-footer, numbering, page-numbering, cv

I'm writing my curriculum

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{currvita}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\tolerance=600 

\setlength{\textheight}{235mm}

\raggedright

\begin{document}

\setlength{\cvlabelwidth}{40mm}

\sffamily

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead[\sffamily Curriculum Vitae]{\sffamily Curriculum Vitae}

\rhead[\sffamily Name]{\sffamily Name}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\date{}

\end{document}
```

I get the correct numbering on each page except the first page, there is no numbering on the first page. If I remove `\thispagestyle{empty}` I get the numbering also on page 1 but I get also  the headers

```
\lhead[\sffamily Curriculum Vitae]{\sffamily Curriculum Vitae}

\rhead[\sffamily Name]{\sffamily Name}
```

which I do not want on the first page. Do you know how can I put the numbering on the first page without having to remove `\thispagestyle{empty}`?

Comment: Where on the first page should the page number be placed? And, what page style should be applied to that number: "1 of n", "1", or something else?

Comment: This might be a duplicate: [Using the `fancyhdr` package, how do I have a footer but no header on the first page only](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163239/5764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a separate page style for the `firstpage` that is different from the regular `fancy` page style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage,lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}% The default page style
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\lhead[\sffamily Curriculum Vitae]{\sffamily Curriculum Vitae}
\rhead[\sffamily Name]{\sffamily Name}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref*{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}% Only this page should have the firstpage style
                         % All other pages will have fancy

\lipsum

\end{document}
```